# Kotlin Room Cannot find getter for field

Tags: android, kotlin, room

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
> E:\MobileProjects\NewsApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\appops\newsapp\models\Article.java:10: error: Cannot find getter for field.
> private java.lang.Integer id;
> [WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
> ^
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Box9a.png)

please help me

Comment: I don't use android, so can't tell if that is normal, but why is your file name `Article.java`, but it contains Kotlin code? Kotlin files end in `.kt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Turkish system language: absurdly, the getter of properties starting with the letter "i" is not produced. eg change name to "uid" instead of "id"

Comment: That it so strange. Is the `i` character treated different in Turkish, like as some sort of control character?